# How to form a variable from matrix elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, variable-definitions

I have matrix with n rows and 2 columns, say `m = {{x11, y12}, {x21, y22}, ..., {xn1, yn2}`.

Now, I want to form three new variables for example:

```
m = {{1, 2}, {0, 2}, {3, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}, {4, 2}}
```

where all elements in second column are 2.

First say variable `v` that will select elements form matrix `m` under these conditions:

> if $x_{i,1} = 0$ then $1$ else $0$

Result in case of above example: `v={0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}`. I construct it like that:

```
one[x_] := If[x == 0, 1, 0];
v=one /@ m[[All,1]]
```

Because `v` and all new other variables have only one column and `n` row I will drop down the index for column in next notation. For example: $v_{i} - v_{i-1}$ refers to the $v_{i,1} - v_{i-1,1}$; $-i$ refers to the $i^{th}$ row.

Second variable say `vv` had to be formed of elements by counting the run sequences of 1 from v:

> if $v_{i} = 1$ then $vv_{i} = v_{i} + vv_{i-1}$ else $0$

Result in the case of the previous example: `vv = {0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0}`, with `v = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}`.

In the end I want to form variable say `f` which is form from elements of first `m` matrix taking into account these rules (conditions):

> if $vv_{i} > 1$ then $f_{i} = f_{i-1} * m_{i,2}$;

so if we take the $6^{th}$ row in previous example `((2*2)*2)`.

> if $vv_{i} = 1$ then $f_{i} = m_{i,2}$;

so second row of $f_{2} = y22$

> else $f_{i} = m_{i,1}$;

so first row of $f_{1} = x11$ or $1$

Final result should be:

> ```
> f = {1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 8, 4)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gets the first two steps:

```
m = {{1, 2}, {0, 2}, {3, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}, {4, 2}};

v = 1 - Unitize[m[[All, 1]]]
(*{0,1,0,1,1,1,0} *)

vv = Flatten@(Accumulate /@ Split@v)
(* {0,1,0,1,2,3,0} *)
```

**Update:** ... the last step

```
ClearAll[ff];
ff[0] = 1;
ff[n_] := Piecewise[{{ff[n-1] m[[n, 2]], vv[[n]] > 1}, {m[[n, 2]], vv[[n]] == 1}}, m[[n, 1]]];

ff /@ Range[7]
(* {1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 8, 4} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, can You help me to change Accumulate function in vv into multiply (vv(i)=vi x vv(i−1)

Comment: @Branimir, how do you initialize your `f(i)`; i.e. what should `f(1)` be?

Comment: Any value, preferably 0. This value will be dropped from further analysis.